Retrieving label boundaries within QGIS Layout maps
Some time ago, I created a custom Python expression function to retrieve the boundaries of manually placed labels in QGIS:
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False, referenced_columns=[])
def getLabelRect(x, y, feature, parent):
    # x,y ... coordinates of the manual label placement
    point=QgsPointXY(x,y)
    buffer=3
    rec=QgsRectangle.fromCenterAndSize(point,buffer,buffer)
    labels=iface.mapCanvas().labelingResults().labelsWithinRect(rec)
    if len(labels)>0:
        label_geom=labels[0].labelGeometry
        return label_geom
        
    return

My goal was to find a solution to another QGIS labeling question: Callout Labels with more lines
Unfortunately, the expression function only fetches the label boundaries within the main map window (iface.mapCanvas()). So my resulting question is: how can I retrieve label boundaries within a QGIS Layout map? ... or in more detail: can I get the map canvas of a Layout map item and use it like iface.mapCanvas()?

You can retrieve the label bounds of the map item in the layout like so:
p = QgsProject.instance()
manager = p.layoutManager()

# get reference to the example layout
layout = manager.layouts()[0]

# find the map item in example layout
map_item = [item for item in layout.items() if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemMap)][0]

label_results =  map_item.previewLabelingResults()

for label in label_results.allLabels():
    print(label.labelGeometry)

Result:
<QgsGeometry: Polygon ((4238472.78748475387692451 6207369.95093432907015085, 4239179.7527904137969017 6207369.95093432907015085, 4239179.7527904137969017 6208985.87163297925144434, 4238472.78748475387692451 6208985.87163297925144434, 4238472.78748475387692451 6207369.95093432907015085))>
<QgsGeometry: Polygon ((4231447.93659377843141556 6207504.37766740098595619, 4232154.90189943835139275 6207504.37766740098595619, 4232154.90189943835139275 6209120.29836605116724968, 4231447.93659377843141556 6209120.29836605116724968, 4231447.93659377843141556 6207504.37766740098595619))>

Note, this returns the corner coordinates of the (rotated) bounding box. It does not give the rendered geometry of a label background with a different shape (e.g. ellipse).

many thanks for the code example ... I must have overlooked previewLabelingResults(). With your help i can now revise my code.

With the help of @Matt I have revised my code example. Now it shows label boundaries in Layout maps as well, even if the labels are not shown in main map canvas. BTW: I'm using the context variables @layout_name and @map_id to retrieve the associated Layout maps.
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False, referenced_columns=[])
def getLabelRect(x, y, feature, parent, context):
    mapItemId = context.variable('map_id')
    point=QgsPointXY(x,y)
    buffer=3
    rec=QgsRectangle.fromCenterAndSize(point,buffer,buffer)
    if mapItemId == 'canvas':
        labelResults=iface.mapCanvas().labelingResults()
    else:
        layoutName = context.variable('layout_name')
        map = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layoutName).itemById(mapItemId)
        labelResults = map.previewLabelingResults()
    
    labels = labelResults.labelsWithinRect(rec)
    if len(labels)>0:
        label_geom=labels[0].labelGeometry
        return label_geom
        
    return

